# How to pass a parameter value to model?

Tags: mosfet, ngspice

I am trying to use mosfet model, and passing the voltage threshold, how ever, I am getting error

```
 unknown parameter (vto)
```

I've read in NGSpice manual, that mosfet level 1 has the param VTO,

the netlist is:

```
vV1 0 3 5v
vV2 0 1 3.5v
mMosfet1 3 1 2 NMOSFET VTO=1.5
VrMeter1 4 proxynode dc 0 
rMeter1 4 2 1e-8 $ 
Rproxy proxynode 0 0.0000001
.dc vV1 5 5 1
.dc vV2 3.5 3.5 1
.control
set units=degrees
.endc
.print dc i(VrMeter1) 
RGRND1 3 proxynode 1000000 
RGRND2 1 proxynode 1000000 
.model NMOSFET NMOS level=1

.end

ngspice stopped due to error, no simulation run!

ERROR: fatal error in ngspice, exit(1)


Error on line 4 :
  mmosfet1 3 1 2 nmosfet vto=1.5
 unknown parameter (vto) 
Process 3935010 dead!
Process 3935010 detected
```

Any idea?

Comment: You need to set `Vto` inside the `.MODEL` definition. What does work in the same line as the MOSFET is the width (`w`), height (`h`), and areas. Maybe also `m` (the multiplier), but I'm not sure in ng-spice (and the manual is far away from me now).

Comment: Thanks, kindly check here http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-html-manual/manual.xhtml at `21.3 MOSFET Characterization` there is an example as you said, but how can I pass the value rather than having it constant at the model?

Comment: Thanks to @SteKulov's comment below: it's not `w/h`, but `w/l`. The message remains, though (also updated the answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.param` statements and then assign the values within curly braces. e.g. (case insensitive):

```
.param x=1.618
M1 3 1 2 NM
.model nm nmos Vto={x}
```

All `.param` statements are evaluated prior to simulation start, and the curly braces tell the engine to evaluate whatever there is enclosed. Since `x` is a `.param`, it's evaluated before the simulation starts, so the curly braces replace `{x}` with its defined value, `1.618`.

As a minor addition, in the comments I mentioned that the MOSFET line can have parameters: width, height, areas. Usually, the areas are calculated from `w` and `l`, so the line could look like this:

```
.param y=0.618
M1 3 1 2 NM w=1 l={y}
```

As it is, `w` is predefined and unchanged, while `l` can be defined and used with a `.step` to see how varying it changes the response. For this particular MOSFET you'll need a hefty workbench.

---

> Thanks, but that leads to use the model only for one mosfet. What if I want to have two mosfets in the circuit each with different VOT, using the same model?

You should have specified this in your OP -- actually, *please do so*.

You will need to use as many `.MODEL` definitions as you have MOSFETs that use that particular change, but there is a shortcut: the [`ako` (a kind of)](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#AKO_Aliases_.28A_Kind_Of.29) keyword. If you already have the `.MODEL` defined in the database, then all you need is to rename each MOSFET that needs a change, preferably in an intuitive manner, and then add (assuming you're "impersonating" the `2N7000`, for example):

```
.model N_3.14 ako:2N7000 vto=3.14
.model N_2.718 ako:2n7000 vto=2.718
...
```

Then having a MOSFET named `N_3.14` will make it behave like a `2N7000` with a 3.14 V threshold; similarly for an `N_2.718`. And, just like in the original answer, you can use `.PARAM` statements to assign to `Vto`.

---

[edit] Thanks to [Ste Kulov's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/610773/how-to-pass-a-parameter-value-to-model/610803?noredirect=1#comment1610186_610803), you need to enable either PSpice, or LTspice compatibility for `ako` to work [/edit]

Comment: Thanks, but that leads to use the model only for one mosfet. What if I want to have two mosfets in the circuit each with different VOT, using the same model?

Comment: @simo I've updated my answer, but this comment needs to be included in your OP -- you have no mention about this.

Comment: Just a heads up that `ako` only works when PSpice compatibility mode [`set ngbehavior=ps`] or PSpice/LTspice joint compatibility mode [`set ngbehavior=ltps`] is enabled within ngspice.  See Section 16.14.5 and/or 16.14.7 of the manual.

Comment: Oh wait.  Another thing.  Just realized it's `W` and `L`, not `W` and `H`.  There is no `H` unless there's some goofy 3D model I don't know about yet.

Comment: @SteKulov Your friends must call you Hawkeye. Thank you for spotting those, and for the flags (they were further down the page when I wrote these, but that was one page too far in the viewer...).

Comment: WARNING: Spotting minor things too frequently may result in not having any friends left!